# Integrating jVectorMap (JS + Jquery) into GWT application

Tags: jquery, gwt, jsni, jvectormap

Hi I try to integrate jVectorMap (JS + Jquery) to GWT. It works well in the Development mode but not on the Webserver.

This is the jVectormap code and my GWT code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        farben = {};
        farben["de"] = "#98BC53";

        $("#karte").vectorMap({
            map: "europe_en",
            backgroundColor: "#4E4943",
            colors: farben,
            hoverOpacity: 0.7,
            hoverColor: false
        });
    });
</script>
```

and GWT code

```
public native void putMyMap() /*-{

    farben = {};
    farben["de"] = "#98BC53";

    $wnd.$('#karte').vectorMap({
        map: "europe_en",
        backgroundColor: "#4E4943",
        colors: farben,
        hoverOpacity: 0.7,
        hoverColor: false
    });
}-*/;
```

Thanks for any ideas and help handed

DK